# django use a model before its definition in another model

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to build a messaging app.

models:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='thread_set')

    def thread_creator(self):
        return self.message_set.first().sender

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, related_name='message_set', blank=True, null=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    body = models.TextField()
```

So, when a message is sent, a new thread is created. And that first message will have a foreignkey relation with that thread. So, any other messages sent to this thread will have its foreignkey relation with the thread. This is working fine.

However, suppose I want to add a reply to a particular message. So now, it should create a new thread for that message, and a message can only have one thread (which will hold other reply messages). This makes one to one relation of the new thread with that message.

So, I changed the Thread model to this:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='thread_set')
    message = models.OneToOneField(Message, blank=True, null=True)
```

But, since Message model is not defined yet, it gives me error:

> NameError: name 'Message' is not defined

How can I use a class model before its defined? Or is there any other way around to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference it by its name (as a string) like so:

```
message = models.OneToOneField('Message', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Yup! This was it. Thank you.